AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'id' flask-login
I'm doing an app with javascript and flask. My app works in localhost with no problems but when i uploaded it to a server that uses apache for dns and links management, it only works in a few navigators like safari and opera but in chrome or firefox it doesn't. I've tried to debugg with the error log of apache and i have this error:
[Wed Jun 05 02:18:12.428382 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 9384] [remote 181.162.24.141:56513]     user = current_user.id
[Wed Jun 05 02:18:12.428389 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 9384] [remote 181.162.24.141:56513]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Wed Jun 05 02:18:12.428395 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 9384] [remote 181.162.24.141:56513] AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'id'

The function i want to use is this:
@app.route('/reservations', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def reservations():
    user = current_user.id
    data = request.get_json()
    seat = data.get('seat')
    date = data.get('date')
    today = data.get('today')
    time = data.get('time')

    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservations WHERE user = %s AND date = %s AND time = %s', (user, date, time))
    user_reservations = cursor.fetchone()[0]

    if user_reservations > 0:
        return jsonify({'message': 'You have a reservation in this day and time'}), 409

    else:
        cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM login WHERE user = %s', (user,))
        name = cursor.fetchone()
        query = 'INSERT INTO reservations (user, seat, date, name, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
        cursor.execute(query, (user, seat, date, name, time,))
        conexion.commit()
        print('Success')
        logout_user()
        return jsonify({'message': 'Reservation created successfully'})

What it can be? It's weird that ir works perfectly in a few navigators (sorry for my english if there's something that you can't understand, you can ask)
I've tried to use flask-session instead but it's the same.

what is the versions of flask and flask-login are you using? I got this error some time ago too (I think I got it when I update flask to v3.0).

there are any error in browser console after you did the request to your login endpoint? (e.g: cors issues)

@vit i have flask v3.0.3 and flask-login v0.6.3. And no, the browser doesn't show any error but if i delete the @login_required decorator it shows this: Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. And it shows a 302 state. Another thing that's not making sense is that the request returns an html instead of a json.

@vit the html that returns is the login view
